# Логические и физические элементы HTML

Tags: html

Почему 
`<b>` - физический, а
`<strong>` - логический?!

Аналогично `<i>` и `<em>`.

Вчера первый раз услышал, что b и strong хоть чем-то различаются, кроме названия.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все. Отыскал. Синонимы они только внешне в обычном браузере. Если копнуть глубже, то

```
<b>
```

обозначает жирный текст. Именно жирный текст(до тех пор, пока это не будет переопределено в CSS).

```
<strong>
```

обозначает выделенный текст. Выделенный не обязательно графически. В обычном браузере он выделяется жирным. Так договорились. Но это совершенно не обязательно: голосовые программы выделяют этот текст интонацией, некоторые мобильные браузеры подчеркивают.

Вот и получается, что `<b>` физически меняет стиль текста на жирный, а `<strong>` - сообщает об изменении логики отображения, не призывая использовать тот или иной стиль.

*ушел убивать себя об стенку*

Answer (score 0):

Тоже впервые слышу о физических элементах, это наверное недавно "изобрели". b и strong не отличаются для человека, но отличаются для поисковых роботов - b жирный шрифт, мол для красоты, а strong - что-то очень важное в тексте, на что хотели обратить внимание.

Comment: я давно об этом читал.вряд ли это для роботов.насколько я помню это делается для браузеров для слабовидящих.